# Which way is true for Exit from app include IF method?

Tags: java, android

How we can exit from app include if method , like this method but it's not true :

```
if (ClassName.this.finish(); == true) {

//code..

}
```

Comment: what you wrote.It don't even compile.Must be a compile error

Comment: Do you want to execute some lines of code *before* the application (or some application) exits?

Comment: Well i need close code that work on if value , i can't using a code like these are : System.exit(0); or Class.this.finish();

Comment: if you want to do something before application closing then put your code on overridden onDestroyMethod

Comment: But Rasel work with onDestroy method is very hard for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't know, what you want to achieve, here are some suggestions:

If you want to finish the activity after some condition has become true:

```
if (activityShouldFinish() == true) {
  ActivityClassName.this.finish();
}
```

Maybe you want to do something before the acitivty is finished (*famous last words*). In this case, override the finish method:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
  doFamousLastWords();
  super.finish();
}
```

Comment: And if you want to check if your activity is about to go, you can call `isFinishinig()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
            //Write your code here

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also kill your process..

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      //Any clean up you wanted to do
       super.onDestroy();
      //you can completely kill your process.
      android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) ;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra semicolon.

```
if (ClassName.this.finish() == true) {

//code..

}
```

Comment: finish() it does not return value.Its void

Comment: yup it's void but i need way for return value.

Comment: so what is the better way like this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Guys , well i want to close my application to stopService() and i don't want to use onDestroy , so which way is better? (we have not any if method for this, i'm confused)